# Java Use OpenCV with FFMPEG for getting Videocapture Webcam Images

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg

I'am using OpenCV for quite some time to grap images from my USB Cam with DirectShow.

```
webcam.open(selectedCam + Videoio.CAP_DSHOW)
```

I'am using the pre-build opencv library directly from the openCV release site. Now I like to use ffmepg as Video I/O API Backend. If I change Videoio.CAP to FFMPEG the webcam can't be opened.

```
webcam.open(selectedCam + Videoio.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

In my project I include the opencv-450.jar and the nativ library from the java folder.

I can't find an example or have not the right experience what to change so FFMPEG is used/working.

Does anybody know what to do so FFMPEG as backend is used ?

Comment: My guess is that it fails as it cannot locate the FFmpeg libraries (third-party). Check if they're installed and added to the library search paths.